# how to include header correctly in the opencl kernel

Tags: header, kernel, opencl

I am writing an opencl kernel with many helper function in the same .cl file. I want to package the helper function into a header file. I read the spec and see I should pass `-I Dir` in the `clCreateProgram` function call.

I am still confused here. When I crate a A.h file to be included in the .cl file. Should I create a corresponding A.c file or A.cl file? 
If I create a corresponding A.c file, some routines in .c file and .cl file might be different and might make the function cannot be used directly by the kernel.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a header file and #include that in the kernel file. So to include `file1.h` in `kernel.cl` you need to add `#include "file1.h"` and as build option pass `-I.` if header file is in the same folder as kernel file or i.e. `-I./include` if in the `include` folder.